# Codeigniter Website is not responding

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using the codeigniter framework for my website.

Previously my website was working fine. But a few days ago I made some changes in code (I add some files for cron job).

When I made these changes my website is not responding it is continuously connecting to the server.

I am using the `stencil` with the codeigniter.

When I use the ordinary codeigniter view function:

```
$this->load->view('view_name');
```

It was working but as I am using stencil paint:

```
$this->stencil->paint('view_name');  // its not working.
```

Website URL: http://blogsetu.com/

Comment: Can you undo the changes and then test the new modifications on a staging server? That might be the best option to make sure new changes don't break anything.

Comment: the connection to the server is timing out so the php is the least of your worries right now, check your nameserver settings

Comment: Thank you for replying I undo the code the code and upload the backup of the previous day but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to read the documentation again there is something you might have missed we can't say any thing without viewing the full source code

However I think you missed to set a layout

from http://scotch.io/docs/stencil

> Bare Minimum to Get Started Set a Layout in your Controller
>
> You always will need to set a layout. This is required for Stencil.
>
> Layouts are located in "/views/layouts/". To learn more, visit the
>   docs about layouts.
>
> $this->stencil->layout('default_layout');          Set and Load a View with
>   the "paint()" function
>
> To set and load a view you will initiate the "paint()" function. This
>   function is the equivalent to "$this->load->view($view)" in
>   Codeigniter.
>
> To learn how to bind data to the view, please click here.
>
> These are located in the "Pages" folder inside of the views folder.
>   The HTML from these pages are made available in the layout as the
>   $content variable.
>
> $this->stencil->paint('example_view');